# How to pass a list of tuples from Python to PHP Script?

Tags: python, php, json, shell

I have a PHP script(index.php) that needs to call a  python script (pos_tagger.py ) and get a list of tuples as a return. I want to send a sentence as a string from the PHP script to the python script. I want the python script to return a list of tuples to the PHP script. I tried to return the list of tuples as a JSON array.

While returning the list of tuples I am getting NULL in the PHP variable.

The code for PHP script **index.php**.

```
<?PHP

$sent = "I want to get tagged";
$command_exec = escapeshellcmd("python ./pos_tagger.py '$sent'");
$str_output = shell_exec($command_exec);

// This should contain the string
echo $str_output.'<br>';

// Use $arr to store the JSON array
$arr = json_decode($str_output);

?>
```

Now I will show 2 cases for which the Output is different but I expected it to be the same.

---

**Case-1** - pos_tagger.py

```
import sys
import nltk
import json

# nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

def myfunc(sent):
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(sent.split())
    return tagged

sent = sys.argv[1]
tagged_words = myfunc(sent)
ans = json.dumps(tagged_words)

print(ans)
```

**Actual Output** in the browser for this case - Nothing (It's blank)

**Expected Output**:

```
[["I", "PRP"], ["want", "VBP"], ["to", "TO"], ["get", "VB"], ["tagged", "VBN"]]
```

**Possible Issue** - $str_output is NULL. I cant understand the reason behind this.

---

**Case-2** - pos_tagger.py - Passing the hardcoded answer and it works.

```
import json
print(json.dumps([("I", "PRP"), ("want", "VBP"), ("to", "TO"), ("get", "VB"), ("tagged", "VBN")]))
```

**Actual Output** in the browser for this case:

```
[["I", "PRP"], ["want", "VBP"], ["to", "TO"], ["get", "VB"], ["tagged", "VBN"]]
```

If anyone can help, it will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what your case 1 and case 2 are. What are you hard-coding?

Comment: Both PHP & Python script are in same folder or different?

Comment: What do you see if you run `python ./pos_tagger.py 'I want to get tagged'` in the terminal.

Comment: ```[("I", "PRP"), ("want", "VBP"), ("to", "TO"), ("get", "VB"), ("tagged", "VBN")]```

This should get generated. In case 2, I am hardcoding this in json.dumps() and it gets displayed perfectly.

Comment: @Barmar the output for ```python ./pos_tagger.py 'I want to get tagged'``` in terminal is
```[["I", "PRP"], ["want", "VBP"], ["to", "TO"], ["get", "VB"], ["tagged", "VBN"]]```

Comment: I don't know what, but your python is broken.  You can see by following @Barmar comment and maybe display the different vars in the python script to see what's broken.

Comment: Yes, @Haridarshan it's in the same folder.

Comment: If you get that output in the terminal, PHP should get the same result. Try adding `2>&1` to the command (you'll have to remove `escapeshellcmd` because it will escape the redirection), so you see error messages.

Comment: @SayantanPal Weird, I've just test your code and its working fine. I'm getting expected result. What is the python version you are using?

Comment: @Barmar I added ```2>&1``` and removed ```escapeshellcmd``` and got this ```Traceback (most recent call last): File "./pos_tagger.py", line 2, in import nltk File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/workspace/test/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in from nltk.collocations import * File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/workspace/test/nltk/collocations.py", line 35, in from nltk.probability import FreqDist File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/workspace/test/nltk/probability.py", line 333 print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ") ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: @Haridarshan I am using Python 3.7.4

Comment: How you've installed `nltk` module? using `pip3` or `pip`. Try reinstalling `nltk` module via `pip3` and ensure `python --version` is `3.x`

Comment: I suspect the webserver is using Python 2.x. Maybe you have something in your .bashrc or .profile that points you to Python 3.x, but the webserver doesn't run your startup files.

Comment: I've tried `nltk v3.5` with `python 2.7` and got the exact error which you've mentioned but it's working absolutely fine with `python 3.x`

Comment: @Haridarshan I used this in terminal to install nltk ```pip install nltk```

Comment: Verify the versions `python  --version` and `pip --version`

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to check the version of the Python I am using for my webserver. I have installed XAMPP to work in local environment.

Comment: You're using windows or linux?

Comment: @Haridarshan ```pip 20.1.1``` and ```Python 3.7.4``` these are the results I got in terminal

Comment: @Haridarshan Linux (elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera x86_64)

Comment: Install nltk again `pip3 install nltk`

Comment: @Haridarshan Yes I did that and it said requirements already satisfied.

Comment: Check with php script

Comment: @Haridarshan In browser it shows ```sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=17, releaselevel='final', serial=0)``` this is the python version although I have 3.7 installed. How do I change this? But in terminal it shows ```sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)```

Comment: Ok, check `python3` path using `which python3` use the full path of python in your php script rather then just `python` and test by executing your php script. If `which python3` doesn't return anything then check for `python3.7` and use that path

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone!!
I solved it. I just needed to call using Python3 instead of Just python in ```$command_exec = "python ./pos_tagger.py '$sent' 2>&1";``` I changed this to ```$command_exec = "python3 ./pos_tagger.py '$sent' 2>&1";``` and everything works as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233026/discussion-between-sayantan-pal-and-haridarshan).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just by changing one of the lines in the **index.php**

Previously Python webserver was 2.x but now I called it using Python3 so it became python 3.x (3.6.9 to be more specific) so NLTK worked perfectly as for nltk to work we needed 3.5+ versions

```
<?PHP

$sent = "I want to get tagged";
$command_exec = escapeshellcmd("python3 ./pos_tagger.py '$sent'");
$str_output = shell_exec($command_exec);

// This should contain the string
echo $str_output.'<br>';

// Use $arr to store the JSON array
$arr = json_decode($str_output);

?>
```